# How to create custom Word dictionaries from .CSV files

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-office, macros, csv

I work with documents that use a lot of specific words that are flagged by the spell checker in Microsoft Word, such as scientific names of insects.

Ideally, I would take data in .CSV format, and be able to remove all of the words that are found in Word's dictionary already.

I am trying to create custom dictionaries based on database information that I can download from resources like the *Entomological Society of America*. I download the name lists in .CSV format, which I use to create a custom dictionary by removing duplicate entries in Excel and pasting it into the new custom dictionary space. The problem is that these data include a lot of words that are already in Word's spellchecker, and I would like to remove them, to create a small, clean custom dictionary that I can share with my colleagues.

Is there an easy way to remove all of the words in a document that are already in the spellchecker? Or export those words that are flagged?

Thanks! I appreciate any help

**Update:** The method that I've finally settled on is a little tedious, but works well enough for me. I create the word lists in Excel, and filter out the duplicates. Then I paste the word list into an empty document, and add the words manually.

I did find a macro that worked for very short lists, but it hung if it was used on a larger list.

Comment: I would put the words in a regular Word document and run spell-check on them. Then use a macro to remove unflagged words and add the flagged to a dictionary. Note that Word's dictionaries are simply lists of words in a text file, they are not really dictionaries.

Comment: That sounds good. I don't know how to tell a macro to select unflagged words, how do you do that?

Comment: That is the subject of a different question. BTW, you want it to add flagged words to the dictionary. I know that macros to do this have been published in forums. Try asking on http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word.